# Rename office-app to office-web-app

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[office-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-app) is easily confused with [apps-for-office](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apps-for-office). The suggested new name for [office-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-app) is [office-web-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-web-app).