# Duplicate tags [apps-for-office] and [office-app]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I looked through [apps-for-office](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apps-for-office) and [office-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-app) and found that both tags are used for the same thing ([Rename office-app to office-web-app](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251991/rename-office-app-to-office-web-app) also mentions this).

Should [office-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-app) become [apps-for-office](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apps-for-office)?

To make things even more confusing Microsoft renamed "Apps for Office" to "Office Add-ins". Those however are quite different from [office-addins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-addins). Therefore I would not suggest to use a tag that contains the word "addin".